# My js scroll animation is not working, i see a lot of ',' expected ts (1005) and (type annotations can only be used in typescript files)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm following a tutorial and I'm near the end, my scrolling animation doesn't seem to work? could anyone point out if I have any mistakes with my javascript as I'm fairly new?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afaqr875gUE&t=486s (in case you were wondering what the tutorial was)

code:

```
document.lastScrollPosition = 0;
document.lastCentered = 0;
document.onWayTo = null;

document.addEventListener('scroll', listener: () => {
  const direction = window.pageYOffset - document.lastScrollPosition > 0 'down' : 'up';
  const sections = [...document.querySelectorAll('selection')];

  if(document.onWayTo === null) {
    const destIndex = direction === 'up' ? document.lastCentered - 1 : document.lastCentered + 1;
    if(destIndex >= 0 && destIndex < sections.length) {
      console.log({destIndex,direction});
     document.onWayTo = destIndex;
      window.scroll(x: 0, sections[destIndex].offsetTop);
    }
  }
  


  sections.forEach((section,index : number) => {
    if(window.pageYOffset === section.offsetTop) {
      document.lastCentered = index;
      section.className = 'action';
      if (document.onWayTo === index) {
        document.onWayTo = null;
      }

    } else{
      section.className = '';
    }

  })



  document.lastScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;

})
```

Comment: Please include your code as text rather than images.

Comment: Don't post code as an image, also review the [How to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before updating your question.

Comment: Try changing to `addEventListener('scroll', () => {` and `sections.forEach((section,index) => {`

Comment: @tromgy thank you for the suggestion however it still seems to not work. I’m getting an unexpected token error  for the 6th line including ‘down’

Comment: `const direction = window.pageYOffset - document.lastScrollPosition > 0 ? 'down' : 'up';` and also `window.scroll(0, sections[destIndex].offsetTop);`. You really need to get a good editor for JavaScript (e.g. VS Code). It will help you to catch and resolve syntax errors like these.

Comment: By using what you changed, it has gotten rid of the errors however the website still doesn't have a scroll effect, ill try to figure it out myself. also, I have been using vs code all along however it only highlights the issues but never has any suggestions.